# Insert Json in Postgres with requests and psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Hi when I try to run the code below I keep getting name 'headers' is not defined, I believe it has something to do with the indentation, I have tried indenting but it then affects the data variable described below

```
import requests
import psycopg2


conn_string = "host='xx' dbname='xx' user='xx' password='xx'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor=conn.cursor()




def main():
    headers = {
        'authority': 'xx-api.xx.com',
        'origin': 'https://www.example.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'referer': 'https://example.com/xx-calendar',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',

    }


response = requests.get('https://example.com/en/api/v1/x/xxx', headers=headers)
data = response.json()['data']


fields = [
            'dateUtc',
            'countryCode',
            'name',
            'potency',
            'previous',
            'unit',
            'volatility'
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO economic_calendar VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,)", tuple(my_data))



    if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything belonging to `main` must be indented the same level:

```
import requests
import psycopg2

conn_string = "host='xx' dbname='xx' user='xx' password='xx'"

def main():
    headers = {
        'authority': 'xx-api.xx.com',
        'origin': 'https://www.example.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'referer': 'https://example.com/xx-calendar',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',

    }

    response = requests.get('https://example.com/en/api/v1/x/xxx', headers=headers)
    data = response.json()['data']


    fields = [
            'dateUtc',
            'countryCode',
            'name',
            'potency',
            'previous',
            'unit',
            'volatility'
    ]

    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    for item in data:
        my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO economic_calendar VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,)", tuple(my_data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But I am now getting a different error:     data = response.json()['data']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str would you know how to solve